# longtable multirow problem with cline and nopagebreak

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, multirow

I have a problem using with the package lontable and multirow together.

It seems that the \* is not avoiding the page breack, if I'm using \cline{i-j} just afterwards.

Here the original code for test.pdf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
{} & {\bf ID} & {\bf name} & {\bf short Description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 1} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
....
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 21} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 22} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 23} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
....
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 35} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Each record of this table is composed by 2 lines.

The results of this code is to break the record 22 in two pages: first line in page 1 and second line in page 2. That means that \* is not working properly.

\* seems to work correct if I remove \cline{2-4] corresponding  to the record 22.
This is the source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\textheight=5\baselineskip
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
{} & {\bf ID} & {\bf name} & {\bf short Description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 1} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 21} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 22} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\*
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 23} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 35} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The record 22 is not divided in two pages anymore, but it there is no cline.

How can I maintain the partial horizontal line, and at the same time avoid the pagebreack?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! This would be easier to debug if your MWE showed the problem (ie the cline occurred at the page break) If you add `\textheight=5\baselineskip` to your preamble you can have short pages so do not need a bigger. I have updated your MWE this time. Also there is no need to sign your name as the system adds your identifier to the end of the post.

Answer (score 16):

`longtable` doesn't do anything special with `\cline` Perhaps it should. This inserts a `\nobreak` in the right place:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\textheight=5\baselineskip
\makeatletter
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
{} & {\bf ID} & {\bf name} & {\bf short Description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 1} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 21} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 22} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\*
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 23} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\bf 35} & \multirow{2}{*}{test1} & {name}& {short descrition} \\* \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{detailed description} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

So that the breaks happen at `\hline` only:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to work fine now... this is really the end of a long nightmare!

Comment: I'm trying to adarpt your solution to booktab's \midrule and \cmidrule(lr){a-b}.

My attempt doesn't work, unfortunately, so I may have to start a new question:

`\makeatletter
\def\@cmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#3%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#4%
  \advance\@multicnt-#4%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\midrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother`

Comment: @Lucas looking at bookabs.sty looks like you intnded to redefine `\@@@cmidrule` with thre `@` not one. also you are omiting most of the booktabs definiion