# table breaks spanning multiple pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking, multirow, supertabular

i'm having an issue with a table that spans multiple pages and breaks across columns that span several rows.  my code is listed below.  the problem is that on page 1, row 1 shows up with foo1, bar1 and yikes1 with no problem.  row 2 and foo2 also shows up on page 1  and then the page breaks, with bar2 and yikes2 ending up on page 2.  i want it to break so that all of row 2 end up on the second page.  the table will grow and shrink, so i'm hoping for a dynamic solution.

```
    \begin {supertabular}{|p{1.0in}|p{3.0in}|m{1.10in}|m{1.25in}|}
\hline
col 1
& col 2
& col 3
& col 4
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*} 
row 1
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\\cline{2-4}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\\cline{2-4}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\\cline{2-4}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*} 
row 2
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\end {supertabular}
```

Comment: Can you also add the preamble of your document? I can't compile it when I copy/paste and I don't know the required packages.

Comment: A full MWE is especially important when you're complaining about improper page breaks.

Answer (score 3):

This is very very similar to the question [longtable multirow problem with cline and nopagebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52100/12850). You could also look there how to make a proper MWE ;-)

Compared to this, your code is lacking the following things:

1. You seem to have `\multirow` syntax wrong: `\multirow{4}{*}{row 1}`looks better here.
2. You need to protect your lines from breaking inside the span of `\multirow`. Using `\\*` is a first step.
3. Still it seems possible for a line to break at a `\cline`. David gave a patch for this.

With these things in mind, I made the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,supertabular,multirow}

\makeatletter
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\vspace*{15cm}

\begin {supertabular}{|p{1.0in}|p{1.0in}|m{1.10in}|m{1.25in}|}
\hline
col 1
& col 2
& col 3
& col 4
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{row 1}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\\cline{2-4}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{row 2}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\end {supertabular}

\end{document}
```

But still I'm getting page breaks :-(

This seems to be a `supertabular` issue. On a first glance at `supertabular`s code, I couldn't find an obvious reason for this.

After replacing `supertabular` by `longtable` everywhere, it works ;-)