# longtable multirow problem with cmidrule and nopagebreak

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, multirow, tabu, booktabs

I'm trying to reimplement the David Carlisle solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/longtable-multirow-problem-with-cline-and-nopagebreak) for breaking
long tables over certain rows (breaking in `\hline` commnands instead `\cline` ones). This solution is complemented with the use of `\\*` command (another example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64956/prevent-longtable-breaking-in-multirow)), and works perfectly with `longtable`and `longtabu` environments.

Now, I would like do it work with the `booktabs` package, which uses a different mechanism to draw lines, especially in `\hline\hline` cases.

Following the procedure given by David, I rewrote the `\@cmidrulea` and `\@cmidruleb` commands, which, according booktabs documentation, actually draw the rules. This is a 'minimal' example:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}   % Para las tablas (varias filas)
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % Colores. Tambien en tablas

\newcommand{\OG}{\cellcolor{orange}}

%%%% Tomado de https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/longtable-multirow-problem-with-cline-and-nopagebreak
\makeatletter

\def\@cmidrulea{%
  \multispan\@cmidla&\multispan\@cmidlb
  \unskip\hskip\cmrkern@l%
  {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule \@height\@thisrulewidth\hfill}%
  \hskip\cmrkern@r\cr
  \noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\@thisrulewidth} %% Inserted \nobreak here
}%

\def\@cmidruleb{% This remains unchanged
  \multispan\@cmidlb
  \unskip\hskip \cmrkern@l%
  {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule \@height\@thisrulewidth\hfill}%
  \hskip\cmrkern@r\cr
  % \noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\@thisrulewidth} %% With this, "almost" works...
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|X[3,lm]|X[1,cm]|X[1,cm]|X[1,cm]|X[1,cm]|X[1,cm]|X[1,cm]|}
  \toprule
  \rowfont\bfseries
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
  elit.
  & Curabitur
  & Nam
  & Pellentesque
  & Donec
  & Curabitur
  & Cras\\*
  \midrule
  \endhead

  \multicolumn{7}{r}{\small \it Continued on next page} \\* \endfoot

  \endlastfoot

  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\OG\textbf{First group heading}}\\*
  \midrule

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Terra & Integer & & Mauris & Mauris &  MC \\
  \midrule

  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus& Terra & Integer &
  & Orci & Mauris & DB \\
  \midrule

  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus& Terra & Integer &
  & Orci & Mauris & DB \\
  \midrule

  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus& Terra & Integer &
  & Orci & Mauris & DB \\
  \midrule

  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}

  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\

  \midrule

  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}

  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\

  \midrule

  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}

  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\

  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\OG\textbf{Second group heading}}\\*
  \midrule

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Terra & Integer & & Mauris & Mauris &  MC \\
  \midrule

  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus& Terra & Integer &
  & Orci & Mauris & DB \\
  \midrule

  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}

  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\

  \midrule

  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}

  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\

  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\OG\textbf{Third group heading}}\\*
  \midrule
  %\cmidrule{1-7} %% Ouch!

  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}

  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\


  \bottomrule 

  \caption{Fiat iustitia, ne pereat mundus.}    
  \label{tab:fiat-iustitia}
  \tabuphantomline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

As you can see if you process the document, there is a page breaking in the third heading group, even with a explicit no break `\\*`  command.

As desperate solution, I've tried replace the `\midrule` command by a less elegant `\cmidrule{1-7}` but this only almost work if I uncomment the `\nobreak` line in `\@cmidruleb` (re)definition. If I do this, the page breaks correctly, but last line is drawn in the next page. I'm also interested in this last case because I'll probably need it with multirow cells in the right side of the table, with `\cmidrule{1-n}` commands.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page breaking typically happens where a `\vskip` (rather than a rule) is added. The following puts `\BT@nobreak` before every vskip added by nooktables (with a default definition of `\relax` then two commands are provided that switch its definition between `\relax` and `\nobreak` so you can prevent page breaks at booktabs rules for sections of the table, specifically around your coloured group headings and in areas spanned by `\multirow`

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}   % Para las tablas (varias filas)
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % Colores. Tambien en tablas

\newcommand{\OG}{\cellcolor{orange}}

%%%% Tomado de http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/longtable-multirow-problem-with-cline-and-nopagebreak
\makeatletter
\let\BT@nobreak\relax
\def\@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4{\global\@cmidla#1\relax
    \global\advance\@cmidla\m@ne
    \ifnum\@cmidla>0\global\let\@gtempa\@cmidrulea\else
    \global\let\@gtempa\@cmidruleb\fi
    \global\@cmidlb#2\relax
    \global\advance\@cmidlb-\@cmidla
    \global\@thisrulewidth=#3
    \@setrulekerning{#4}
    \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\BT@nobreak\vskip \aboverulesep\fi
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}\@gtempa
    \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\futurenonspacelet\@tempa\@xcmidrule}

\def\@BTendrule{\ifx\@tempa\toprule\global\@lastruleclass=\@thisruleclass
  \else\ifx\@tempa\midrule\global\@lastruleclass=\@thisruleclass
  \else\ifx\@tempa\bottomrule\global\@lastruleclass=\@thisruleclass
  \else\ifx\@tempa\cmidrule\global\@lastruleclass=\@thisruleclass
  \else\ifx\@tempa\specialrule\global\@lastruleclass=\@thisruleclass
  \else\ifx\@tempa\addlinespace\global\@lastruleclass=\@thisruleclass
  \else\global\@lastruleclass=\z@\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\@ne\relax\else\BT@nobreak\vskip\@belowrulesep\fi
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}}

\def\@xcmidrule{%
   \ifx\@tempa\cmidrule
       \BT@nobreak\vskip-\@thisrulewidth
       \global\@lastruleclass=\@ne
   \else \ifx\@tempa\morecmidrules
       \BT@nobreak\vskip \cmidrulesep
       \global\@lastruleclass=\@ne\else
       \BT@nobreak\vskip \belowrulesep
       \global\@lastruleclass=\z@
   \fi\fi
   \ifnum0=`{\fi}}

\def\@BTrule[#1]{%
\BT@nobreak
  \global\@thisrulewidth=#1\relax
  \ifnum\@thisruleclass=\tw@\vskip\@aboverulesep\else
  \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\vskip\@aboverulesep\else
  \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\@ne\vskip\doublerulesep\fi\fi\fi
  \ifx\longtable\undefined
     \let\@BTswitch\@BTnormal
  \else\ifx\hline\LT@hline
     \let\@BTswitch\@BLTrule
  \else
     \let\@BTswitch\@BTnormal
  \fi\fi
  \@BTswitch}

\def\@cmidrulea{%
  \multispan\@cmidla&\multispan\@cmidlb
  \unskip\hskip\cmrkern@l%
  {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule \@height\@thisrulewidth\hfill}%
  \hskip\cmrkern@r\cr
  \noalign{\BT@nobreak\vskip-\@thisrulewidth} %% Inserted \BT@nobreak here
}%

\def\nobtrulebreaks{\noalign{\global\let\BT@nobreak\nobreak}}
\def\allowbtrulebreaks{\noalign{\global\let\BT@nobreak\relax}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|X[3,lm]|X[1,cm]|X[1,cm]|X[1,cm]|X[1,cm]|X[1,cm]|X[1,cm]|}
  \toprule
  \rowfont\bfseries
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
  elit.
  & Curabitur
  & Nam
  & Pellentesque
  & Donec
  & Curabitur
  & Cras\\*
  \midrule
  \endhead

  \multicolumn{7}{r}{\small \it Continued on next page} \\* \endfoot

  \endlastfoot
\nobtrulebreaks
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\OG\textbf{First group heading}}\\*
  \midrule


  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Terra & Integer & & Mauris & Mauris &  MC \\
\allowbtrulebreaks
  \midrule

  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus& Terra & Integer &
  & Orci & Mauris & DB \\
  \midrule

  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus& Terra & Integer &
  & Orci & Mauris & DB \\
  \midrule

  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus& Terra & Integer &
  & Orci & Mauris & DB \\
  \midrule

  \nobtrulebreaks
  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}

  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\
\allowbtrulebreaks
  \midrule
  \nobtrulebreaks
  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}

  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\
\allowbtrulebreaks
  \midrule

\nobtrulebreaks
  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}

\allowbtrulebreaks
  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\

\nobtrulebreaks
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\OG\textbf{Second group heading}}\\*
  \midrule

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Terra & Integer & & Mauris & Mauris &  MC \\
\allowbtrulebreaks
  \midrule

  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus& Terra & Integer &
  & Orci & Mauris & DB \\
  \midrule

  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}

  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\

  \midrule

\nobtrulebreaks
  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}
\allowbtrulebreaks
  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\

\nobtrulebreaks
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\OG\textbf{Third group heading}}\\*
  \midrule
  %\cmidrule{1-7} %% Ouch!


  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    senectus} &
  Phasellus (vehicula augue eu neque) & Integer & \textbf{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
      Curabitur\\
      Phasellus
    }
  } & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\*

  \cmidrule{2-7}
\allowbtrulebreaks
  & Donec (vehicula augue eu neque) & Puella &
  \textbf{Curabitur Phasellus Magna} & Mauris & \textbf{Magna} &  DB \\


  \bottomrule 

  \caption{Fiat iustitia, ne pereat mundus.}    
  \label{tab:fiat-iustitia}
  \tabuphantomline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```