# Force pagebreak behind hline in longtable

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, tabularx, ltablex

I try to force the pagebreaks **only** behind `\hline` and **not** behind a `\hhline{|~|----}`

**The first MWE shows the wrong behavior**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Just for the MWE

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext\\
TEXT\\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{24mm}|p{19.5mm}|p{28.5mm}|p{19mm}|>{\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray} Test\newline Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
\endhead
Test & Test & Test & Test & Test\\\hhline{|~|----}
& Test\newline Test & Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
Test & Test & Test\newline Test & Test & Test\\\hhline{|~|----} 
& Test\newline Test & Test & Test & Test\\
\hline
Test & Test & Test & Test & Test\\\hhline{|~|----} 
& Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
Test & Test & Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\\hhline{|~|----} 
& Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**The second MWE shows the right behavior**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Just for the MWE

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext\\
%TEXT\\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{24mm}|p{19.5mm}|p{28.5mm}|p{19mm}|>{\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray} Test\newline Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
\endhead
Test & Test & Test & Test & Test\\\hhline{|~|----}
& Test\newline Test & Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
Test & Test & Test\newline Test & Test & Test\\\hhline{|~|----} 
& Test\newline Test & Test & Test & Test\\
\hline
Test & Test & Test & Test & Test\\\hhline{|~|----} 
& Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
Test & Test & Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\\hhline{|~|----} 
& Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to force the right behavior automatically?

Comment: You could try using \\* where you do not want a page break to happen and \\ where a page break would be acceptable.

Comment: What is the purpose of >{\arraybackslash}X, why not simply use X?

Comment: @leandriis How can I realize your first comment? I get errors if I leave out `\\` before `\hhline{|~|----}` The use of `>{\arraybackslash}X` is needed in my document but doesn't matter in this MWE.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `\\*\hhline{|~|----}` does not seem to work. However, you could switch to `\cline{2-5}` and use the workaround presented here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52101/134144

Answer (score 1):

In the following solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package , we define a unbreakable `\myhline`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext} % Just for the MWE
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrTemplate{head,foot}{empty}
\NewTableCommand{\myhline}{\cline{2-5}\nopagebreak}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Title},
]{
  colspec = {|p{24mm}|p{19.5mm}|p{28.5mm}|p{19mm}|X|},
  row{1} = {gray8},
  rowhead = 1,
}
\hline
  Test\newline Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
  Test & Test & Test & Test & Test\\
\myhline
       & Test\newline Test & Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
  Test & Test & Test\newline Test & Test & Test\\
\myhline
       & Test\newline Test & Test & Test & Test\\
\hline
  Test & Test & Test & Test & Test\\
\myhline
       & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
  Test & Test & Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\myhline
       & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\newline Test & Test\\
\hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]