# Longtable with multirow

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, multirow

I would like to create this long table:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  What did you try so far in order tom combine `\multirow` with `longtable`? You can use the `\multirow` command inside of a longtable as you can use it inside of a regular tabular environment. However, you should be aware that it might interfere with pagebreaks, so caution there. Probably a customized enumerate list with a nested description list could be an alternative for you?

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: What you mean with "longtable"? That your table is longer than one page? And what is the problem at writing (this relative simply) table. Basic information you can find in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: Yes, My table is longer than one page. When I add \multyrow in my code in this longtable Latex bring me a error.

Comment: My code is something like this (in a table, no longtable):

Comment: See the description

Comment: Please add the code directly into your question instead of just showing a screenshot of the code. This makes tessting easier.

Comment: Since you mention "brings me an error": Which error messae do you get specifically?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|p{7cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{multicolumn text here}\\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{1} & text & \\ \cline{2-3}
                   & text & \\ \cline{2-3}
                   & text & \\ \cline{2-3}
                   & text & \\ \cline{2-3}
                   & text & \\ \cline{2-3}
                   & text & \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}` should serve as a place to start from.

Answer (score 4):

- Please in question always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document which reproduce your problem.
- The MWE must not be presented as an image of your code but must be a copy from the editor Which we can copy in our computers and test as it is.
- I sugest to use `xltabular` package, which is combination of `longtable` and `tabularx` package.
- Having `multirow`s in long table can cause problems at splitting table between pages. Therefore in the MWE below is used `\pagebreak` which inserted in table such, that on each page is complete `multirow` cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| c | l | L |}
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \hline
\endhead
%
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Test Script}   \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{1}    
    & Status            &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Details           &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Test Data         &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Expected Result   &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Actual Result     &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Issues            &           \\  
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{2}
    & Status            &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Details           &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Test Data         &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Expected Result   &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Actual Result     &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Issues            &           \\  
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{3}
    & Status            &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Details           &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Test Data         &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Expected Result   &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Actual Result     &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Issues            &           \\  
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{4}
    & Status            &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Details           &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Test Data         &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Expected Result   &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Actual Result     &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Issues            &           \\  
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{5}
    & Status            &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Details           &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Test Data         &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Expected Result   &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Actual Result     &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Issues            &           \\  
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{6}
    & Status            &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Details           &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Test Data         &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Expected Result   &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Actual Result     &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Issues            &           \\  
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{7}
    & Status            &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Details           &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Test Data         &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Expected Result   &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Actual Result     &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Issues            &           \\  
\hline
    \pagebreak   % <---
    
\multirow{6}{*}{8}
    & Status            &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Details           &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Test Data         &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Expected Result   &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Actual Result     &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Issues            &           \\  
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{9}
    & Status            &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Details           &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Test Data         &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Expected Result   &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Actual Result     &           \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Issues            &           \\  
\hline
     \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

The top part of the first page:

[image]

The second page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should define a command, instead of repeating over and over the same tokens, which is error prone.

The code below is based on Žarko's, but with a trick from [longtable multirow problem with cline and nopagebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52100/4427) to avoid unwanted page breaks.

The macro `\block` has seven arguments, which can be filled with the actual data in the specified order.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,xltabular}

\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52101/4427
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\block}[7]{%
 % #1 = number, #2 = Status, #3 = Details, #4 = Test Data,
 % #5 = Expected Result, #6 = Actual Result, #7 = Issues
 \multirow{6}{*}{#1}
 & Status & #2 \\* \cline{2-3}
 & Details & #3 \\*  \cline{2-3}
 & Test Data & #4 \\* \cline{2-3}
 & Expected Result & #5 \\* \cline{2-3}
 & Actual Result & #6 \\* \cline{2-3}
 & Issues & #7 \\ \hline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|c|l|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Test Script} \\
\hline
\endhead
\block{1}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{2}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{3}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{4}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{5}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{6}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{7}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{8}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{9}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{10}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{11}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{12}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{13}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{14}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{15}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the advantage, besides shortening the input? With just a change to the definition and to the table preamble, you can get a different output.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular,booktabs}

\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52101/4427
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\block}[7]{%
 % #1 = number, #2 = Status, #3 = Details, #4 = Test Data,
 % #5 = Expected Result, #6 = Actual Result, #7 = Issues
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{\itshape Test #1} \\*
 Status & #2 \\*
 Details & #3 \\*
 Test Data & #4 \\*
 Expected Result & #5 \\*
 Actual Result & #6 \\*
 Issues & #7 \\ \midrule
}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Test Script} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\block{1}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{2}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{3}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{4}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{5}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{6}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{7}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{8}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{9}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{10}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{11}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\block{12}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]